# biblatex - multileveled bibliography with shorthands

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm pretty new with LaTeX, BibLaTex & co. In fact I'm trying to write my first text with it and already have a special request for citation and bibliography.

1) I want to use shorthands in my cites, like [Catalogue 1], so I use `style=verbose-ibid`

2) My bibliography should (partially) be "multileveled", so it looks a bit like a TOC:

> [Catalogue 1]
>
> - Content 1
> - Content 2
> - Content 3
>
> [Catalogue 2]
>
> - Content 1
> - Content 2
> - Content 3

**Example**

Cite (Footnote):

> DudeA, B.: Supertext. In: [Catalogue 1], p.4 <- using only shorthand, no year or something!

Cite (Footnote) on next page:

> DudeA, "Supertext". In: [Catalogue 1], p.5 <- using shortTITLE

Bibliography:

> [Catalogue1]   Catdude, D.: Big Catalogue of something. Montana, 1988.
>
> - DudeA, B.: Supertext, p.5-8. <- no shorthand, no year, nothing more printed!

How can I manage that?